# JavaScript code to edit tags without editing a question: Will it be added to each SE site?

Tags: support, tags

On the *English Language and Usage* Stack Exchange site, I can edit question tags without editing the question body (I can edit the question wrote by another user).

Will the code that handles that be added to each Stack Exchange site (including Stack Overflow)?

[image: Tags Edit]

Comment: It already has been.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That ability is granted at 10k reputation on non-beta sites. On beta sites, the equivalent reputation requirement is only 2k, which you have already reached on English.SE.

See [the announcement](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/new-10k-feature-inline-tagging/) and [reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared).

Comment: Thank you, mmyers. As it is a recent feature, I thought it was a possibility that who can edit other users' posts would have.